# ASP.NET: Cache setting is inherited by referenced files that are called from the main html file?

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

My environment:

- ASP.NET Core MVC

I added the attiribute `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]` onto the top of the Action method in a controller. By this cache setting, the html won't be cached. I understand this. But how about resources like JavaScript, CSS, image files that are referenced by the page? The cache setting set to the page is inherited by all the referenced files that are called from the main html file?